# using index values to select items from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a pair of numpy arrays `X` and `I` that look like this (X is 2D, I is 1D)

```
X               I
-----------------
3.4  9.13       0
3.5  3.43       1
3.6  2.01       2
3.7  6.11       0
3.8  4.95       1
3.9  7.02       2
4.0  4.41       3
4.1  0.23       0
4.2  0.99       1
4.3  1.02       0
4.4  5.61       1
4.5  7.55       2
4.6  8.10       0
4.7  0.33       2
4.8  0.80       1
```

I would like to do two things:

1. `Y = indexby(X,I,I0)`: Given a value I0, find the rows of X which have matching values in I. For example if I is 2, I would want to find the following array:

   ```
   3.6  2.01  
   3.9  7.02  
   4.5  7.55  
   4.7  0.33
   ```
2. `Y = indexby(X,I)`: Return a dictionary with all the possible keys `k` such that `Y[k] == indexby(X,I,k)`. In my example data, this would produce the following:

   ```
   Y[0] = 
   3.4  9.13       
   3.7  6.11       
   4.1  0.23       
   4.3  1.02       
   4.6  8.10       

   Y[1] = 
   3.5  3.43      
   3.8  4.95      
   4.2  0.99      
   4.4  5.61       
   4.8  0.80  

   Y[2] = 
   3.6  2.01  
   3.9  7.02  
   4.5  7.55  
   4.7  0.33  

   Y[3] = 
   4.0  4.41
   ```

Are there numpy functions which do this? I'm not sure what to look for so it's hard to find them.

I know I can do this manually, but for performance reasons I would like to use a builtin numpy function since the arrays in my application are typically have row counts in the 100,000 - 1,000,000 range.

Comment: `np.where` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: `np.searchsorted` is another nice one

Comment: These two are perfectly solved by pandas

Comment: @Happy001 ...could you elaborate? I'm already using pandas elsewhere + can use it here if it makes sense.

Comment: @JasonS see my answer below. I highly recommend `pandas` (especially if you've worked with SAS/R). It's based on `numpy`.

Answer (score 4):

There are some higher-level functions, but let's see how to do it using just the simplest stuff in the library, because you're going to need those simple functions every day.

```
>>> matches = (I == 2)
>>> matches
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)    
>>> indices = np.nonzero(matches)
>>> indices
(array([ 2,  5, 11, 13]),)
>>> xvals = X[indices]
>>> xvals
array([[ 3.6 ,  2.01],
       [ 3.9 ,  7.02],
       [ 4.5 ,  7.55],
       [ 4.7 ,  0.33]])
```

The last step may look confusing. See [Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) in the tutorial for further information.

Once you understand how the `==` operator and [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) work, look through the other functions in the same section as `nonzero` and you should find two shorter ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to try `pandas`, it's really powerful in `groupby` data. Here's how you can achieve what you need:

```
In [34]: import numpy as np

In [35]: import pandas as pd

#I defined you X, I already
In [36]: X
Out[36]: 
array([[ 3.4 ,  9.13],
       [ 3.5 ,  3.43],
       [ 3.6 ,  2.01],
       [ 3.7 ,  6.11],
       [ 3.8 ,  4.95],
       [ 3.9 ,  7.02],
       [ 4.  ,  4.41],
       [ 4.1 ,  0.23],
       [ 4.2 ,  0.99],
       [ 4.3 ,  1.02],
       [ 4.4 ,  5.61],
       [ 4.5 ,  7.55],
       [ 4.6 ,  8.1 ],
       [ 4.7 ,  0.33],
       [ 4.8 ,  0.8 ]])

In [37]: I
Out[37]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1], dtype=int64)

In [38]: dataframe=pd.DataFrame (data=X, index=I, columns=['X1','X2'])

In [39]: dataframe.index.name='I' #This is not necessary
In [40]: print dataframe
    X1    X2
I           
0  3.4  9.13
1  3.5  3.43
2  3.6  2.01
0  3.7  6.11
1  3.8  4.95
2  3.9  7.02
3  4.0  4.41
0  4.1  0.23
1  4.2  0.99
0  4.3  1.02
1  4.4  5.61
2  4.5  7.55
0  4.6  8.10
2  4.7  0.33
1  4.8  0.80
```

This defines a dataframe with `I` as index and `X` as data. Now if you need rows with `I=2`, you can do

```
In [42]: print dataframe.ix[2]
    X1    X2
I           
2  3.6  2.01
2  3.9  7.02
2  4.5  7.55
2  4.7  0.33
```

If you want to list all groups:

```
In [43]: for i, grouped_data in dataframe.groupby(level='I'): #without level=, you can group by a regular column like X1
   ....:     print i
   ....:     print grouped_data
   ....:     
0
    X1    X2
I           
0  3.4  9.13
0  3.7  6.11
0  4.1  0.23
0  4.3  1.02
0  4.6  8.10
1
    X1    X2
I           
1  3.5  3.43
1  3.8  4.95
1  4.2  0.99
1  4.4  5.61
1  4.8  0.80
2
    X1    X2
I           
2  3.6  2.01
2  3.9  7.02
2  4.5  7.55
2  4.7  0.33
3
   X1    X2
I          
3   4  4.41
```

If you just want to see statistics of each group, you can do

```
In [47]: print dataframe.groupby(level='I').sum() #try other funcs like mean, var, .
     X1     X2
I             
0  20.1  24.59
1  20.7  15.78
2  16.7  16.91
3   4.0   4.41
```

Comment: sweet, I've used pandas before, just can never remember the magic functions

Answer (score 1):

First I'll show a nice solution using [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  The linked documentation has lots of good information on various way to index, sort, and create them.

Lets define a subset of your data,

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array( [[3.4,9.13], [3.5,3.43], [3.6,2.01], [3.7,6.11], 
               [3.8,4.95], [3.9,7.02], [4.0,4.41]] )

I = np.array( [0,1,2,0,1,2,3], dtype=np.int32 )
```

### Structured Array

If we make a structured array (i.e. an array of structs) from this data, the problem is trivial,

```
sa = np.zeros( len(X), dtype=[('I',np.int64),('X',np.float64,(2))] )
```

Here we've made an empty structured array.  Each element of the array is a 64 bit integer and a 2 element array of 64 bit floats.  The list passed to `dtype` defines the struct with each tuple representing a component of the struct.  The tuples contain a label, a type, and a shape.  The shape part is optional and defaults to a scalar entry.

Next we fill the structured array with your data,

```
sa['I'] = I
sa['X'] = X
```

At this point you can access the records like so,

```
>>> sa['X'][sa['I']==2]
array([[ 3.6 ,  2.01],
       [ 3.9 ,  7.02]])
```

Here we've asked for all the 'X' records and indexed them using the bool array created by the statement `sa['I']==2`.  The dictionary you want can then be constructed using a comprehension,

```
d = { i:sa['X'][sa['I']==i] for i in np.unique(sa['I']) }
```

Next are two solutions using standard numpy arrays. The first uses `np.where` and leaves the arrays unmodified and another that involves sorting the arrays which should be faster for large `I`.

### Using `np.where`

The use of `np.where` is not strictly necessary as arrays can be indexed using the bool array produced from `I==I0` below, but having the actual indices as ints is useful in some circumstances.

```
def indexby1( X,I,I0 ):
    indx = np.where( I==I0 )
    sub = X[indx[0],:]
    return sub

def indexby2( X,I ):
    d = {}
    I0max = I.max()
    for I0 in range(I0max+1):
        d[I0] = indexby1( X, I, I0 )
    return d

d = indexby2( X, I )
```

### Sorting and pulling out chunks

Alternatively you can use the sorting solution mentioned and just return chunks,

```
def order_arrays( X, I ):
    indx = I.argsort()
    I = I[indx]
    X = [indx]  # equivalent to X = X[indx,:]
    return X, I

def indexby(X, I, I0=None):
    if I0 == None:
        d = {}
        for I0 in range(I.max()+1):
            d[I0] = indexby( X, I, I0 )
        return d
    else:
        ii = I.searchsorted(I0)
        ff = I.searchsorted(I0+1)
        sub = X[ii:ff]
        return sub

X,I = order_array( X, I )
d = indexby( X, I )
```

Here I've combined the two previous functions into one recursive function as you described the signature in your question.  This will of course modify the original arrays.